# Python and SQlite

Tags: python, sqlite

i tried to save cursor_1 value,
but i can't it.

```
cursor_1 = conn.execute("SELECT cost from test where name like 'fish'")
for row in cursor_1:
  print "cost = ", row[0]
```

i want to save each 'cursor_1' value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = conn.execute("SELECT cost from test where name like 'fish'").fetchall()
```

Also, chances are, you don't need to use a cursor for whatever you are doing.